# generate two random number with specific rules

Tags: c++, random

I'm writing a code that generate two random integer and display the result of dividing the first number by the second.
I want the first integer to be more than the second integer and the result of the division without remainder (an integer number)

I tried using do while loop and continue to change the integers until it generate the numbers as I wanted.

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 rd(device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random(1, 100);

int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;

do
{
    firstNumber = random(rd);
    secondNumber = random(rd);
}
while ((firstNumber < secondNumber) && (firstNumber % secondNumber != 0));

int result = firstNumber / secondNumber;

//print the integer to check it
std::cout << firstNumber << std::endl; 
std::cout << secondNumber << std::endl;
```

each time I run this code it always give me the first integer more than the second. but the division result will be with remainder

Comment: You could use two distributions: One that is created after you generate the first number, and which have the first number minus one as the upper limit. Then you don't need a loop for that part anyway.

Comment: The while loop stops if the condition is false. The condition is false if `firstNumber >= secondNumber` OR the remainder is zero. (`!(a && b) = !a || !b`) Change the operator in your condition for an OR so you get `!(a || b) = !a && !b`.

Comment: Of course it is easier to construct your condition rather than expect two random numbers to adhere to it: `secondNumber = random(rd); firstNumber = secondNumber * random(rd)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup, but then the first distribution should probably be `2,100` and not `1,100`. Otherwise you risk that the first random number rolls a 1 and then the second distribution becomes `1,0`.

Comment: @Botje but i used AND (&&) not OR (||) in the while loop

Comment: And that is wrong. Take `firstNumber=5` `secondNumber=3`: `5 < 3 && 5 %3 != 0` === `false && true` === false. You want *both* conditions to be false.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and how about the second condition that the two number give result without remainder

Comment: You can omit the first condition entirely by just conditionally swapping the numbers. This doesn't change the bias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop check is wrong! Try this …

```
do
{
    firstNumber = random(rd);
    secondNumber = random(rd);
} while ((firstNumber <= secondNumber) || (firstNumber % secondNumber != 0));
```

You need to keep running the loop until both conditions are met, so if either one **__or__** the other is not, keep trying!

Also, if you have `<` as your first comparison, rather than `<=`, chances are you'll get both numbers the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few bugs in your conditional checks. But another approach would be to generate the first number based on the result of the second number drawing:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random(1, 50);
secondNumber = random(rd);
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random(2, 100 / secondNumber);
    firstNumber = random(rd) * secondNumber;
}
```

which eliminates the need for a condition check.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick the first number randomly: `num1`.
2. Pick a second number > 1 randomly: `num2`.
3. Your larger number is `num1 * num2`.  Your smaller number is `num1`.  The result of the division is `num2`.